# Microblaze cross compiler cannot find clock_gettime

Tags: c, linux, xilinx

I'm using a Xililnx borad on which a Linux (kernel version 3.0) is running. A microblaze is configured on the board.

My host machine runs Ubuntu 12.04 X86_64 and toolchain (tools-4.1.2-mb-ctng-v1.4-x86_64.tar.bz2) is installed.

I wrote a user mode application and try to use clock_gettime to measure its performance. I included time.h (also tried sys/time.h) . But when I try to compile it, the compiler always gives me errors that "implicit declaration of function clock gettime"

I tried to define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 199309L in my code, but it say the _POSIX_C_SOURCE is already defined.

I use the eclipse as my IDE, and have setup the cross complie environment.

Is there any suggestion?  I have another question that where can I find the embedded linux header files and libs for my program? Does the cross compiler take care of it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you use `#undef`?

Answer (score 1):

Your toolchain may have not support for this function. Check if `_POSIX_TIMERS` in `unistd.h` has a value greater than 0. That indicates that the `clock_*` functions are available. As a failsafe method you can use `clock()` at the cost of a maybe lower resolution if there's no support for the former.